# How to stash a single untracked file out of a group of hundreds of both modified and untracked files in the git?

Tags: magento2.3, git

I did an upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 resulting in hundreds of files being modified while some were newly added. I added another untracked file not related to the upgrade in anyway, and know exactly what the file name is. Is there a git command or something to stash this particular untracked file by mentioning only the file name that I want stashed? I know this files resides on the file system.

Comment: You say 'hundreds of files being changed', does this mean you're tracking the /vendor directory? Personally, I don't track that directory. Because composer manages it. I pull to the server from dev, then composer update, which updates the /vendor directory.

Comment: I did two things. 1 Upgraded Magento to 2.3.5 and left these files on the dev server without pushing to the remote (bit bucket). 2. I added a new file in a custom module and FTPied it so this one is lost in the ocean of huge number of files. I want to only remove this one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime if we change files and folder permission than also shows as modified files

so can you try with first this command ?

`git config core.filemode false`

And than for stashing single file you can give command like below.

`git stash push -m <message> <path-of-file>`

Comment: I haven't tried to change the permission for either files or folders. I did two things. 1 Upgraded Magento to 2.3.5 and left these files on the dev server without pushing to the remote. 2. I added a new file in a custom module and FTPied it so this one is lost in the ocean of huge number of files.

Comment: you added new file in which folder vendor folder ?

Comment: I added an XML file in app/code. I never touch vendor folder.Vendor folder got updated due to Magento upgrade as usual.

Comment: https://bluecast.tech/blog/git-stash/#:~:text=git%20stash%20one%20file,push%20command%20would%20be%20enough. - this is best blog for all type of stash files

Comment: Thanks Parul, very useful guide and your command does the job.

Comment: thank you ..Ready to help anytime

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Magentos official .gitignore and adding to it, please see;
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-gitignore.html

Workflow example;

- composer.json is tracked in this git repo, you make development and staging changes which update this file.
- When you `git pull` to your server(s), you should then run `composer update`, this will check your composer.json file, and update the `/vendor` directory as required.
- This way of working will keep your git repo clean, and also ensure devs aren't modifying core files `/vendor` should never be coded into directly, as composer will over-write changes (changes should always be made by over-riding in the `/app` directory.

So, in your case - you need to add this `.gitignore` from magento, because you shouldn't see hundreds of git entries in a Magento upgrade. I'd recommend adding this gitignore, back up the composer.json, then `git stash` all changes, run `composer update` to pull the 2.3.5 changes, and work this way going forward for no headaches.